# Null or empty instead of 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a new table with:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`tab1` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL , `age` INT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

When I insert a new row, but want to keep `age` empty, I do:

```
INSERT INTO `tab1` (`id`, `Name`, `Age`) VALUES (NULL, 'Peter', '');
```

I get this entry:

```
| id | name  | age |
|----|-------|-----|
| 1  | Peter | 0   |
```

Why the age column just doesn't remain empty or `NULL`?
How can I set a default value, so that it just remains empty, when no value is specified while inserting?

Comment: because you are giving it a value, if you want `NULL` then use `NULL` instead of `''`

Comment: you have null in the first column -- can't you see column 1 and 3 are different?

Comment: @Dresden -- that is false -- integers don't contain 0 when they contain nothing they contain null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the column is of type `int` the DB tries to convert the string `''` to a number. That would be `0`.

Just use `null` instead of `''` if you don't have a value. That is what `null` is for.

Comment: Is there any chance, that the database automatically converts empty values to NULL? Otherwise I would need to scan all inserts and do it myself.

Comment: just run `update your_table set age = null where age = 0`

Comment: BTW you better save the date of birth since you don't need to update that. The age needs to be updated all the time to be correct

Comment: @juergend - but I want to be 21 forever!